# reset enumerator to start for Lumenworks CSV Reader

Tags: c#, csv

I am using the CSV Reader from Lumenworks and its great but the `CurrentRecordIndex` value is set only so when I get to the end of the file, and I want to read it again I can't since the current record is set to last item. Is there a way to reset that?

```
        List<object> output = new List<object>();

        var col = this.InternalCsv.GetFieldIndex(header);
        var e = this.InternalCsv.GetEnumerator();
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            output.Add(e.Current[col]);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try [**IEnumerator.Reset**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.reset(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
e.Reset();
```

> Sets the enumerator to its initial position, which is before the first
>   element in the collection.

Or just Get the enumerator again.

```
var secondEnumerator = this.InternalCsv.GetEnumerator();
```

**Also why you need to enumerate it again when you have the data in the** `List<object> output = new List<object>();` , use the data in the list !

Comment: Well i would but what I need is ability to call the same function with a different `col` value. What happens is that i have the CsvReader stored internally and once I iterate over it, its current index gets set to last item. Then I am calling the same method again, and it needs to reset the enumerator or i am toast. :-) Your solution is good. Thank you.

Comment: @konrad you are welcome, mark the answer as correct if helped you.